# How Do I Pass Parameters to a Queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 to create a simple queue that will resize an uploaded image. I cannot figure out how to pass parameters to the queue, such as the temporary file location of the image. My colleagues have used older versions of Laravel where a string could be passed to a job eg:

```
$this->dispatch(new ExampleJob($foo));
```

However, in Laravel 5.5 passing a string in the same way, eg:

```
ExampleJob::dispatch($foo);
```

will trigger a 'BindingResolutionException' exception as it's expecting a model to serialize.

If that's the case, how do I pass anything else in?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#creating-jobs  You can pass additional arguments through the constructor and reference them in the handle method.

Answer (score 3):

Something Like this works for me in Laravel 5.7 and Laravel 5.5...

```
ExampleJob::dispatch($foo);
```

Then the class and constructor look like this...

```
<?php

class ExampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $foo;

    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $bar = $this->foo;
    }
}
```